# NoReverseMatch at /admin/ Reverse for 'logout' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$admin/logout\\/$']

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

my code for MainProjects.urls is

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include


admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',include('register_complaint.urls')),
    url(r'^register/',include('register_complaint.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/$', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I have tried removing '$' from 'admin' still the same error occurs.

Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/
Django Version: 2.0.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'logout' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$admin/logout\/$']

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the $ from the regexp because you we are appending the included urls to the end of the regular expression.

The `$` in a regular expression represents the end of the string, and it would make sense in an urlpattern that points directly in a view. but a urlpattern that includes another urlpattern is supposed to read only the first part of the URL, because the remaining part is read by the included one. from this the need to begin with ^ and to not append the $.

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

and ensure `'django.contrib.admin'` is added to the `INSTALLED_APPS` settings for your project. Apart from that, everything should work.

Comment: As I had mentioned the same error persists without '$' at  the end. And django.contrib.admin is added too.